# Issue in removing all the nodes from XML file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to remove all the nodes from the XML file. But it's removing the root node open tag also .Using C# anf Linq

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--Log the error count and error message-->
<root>
    <ErrData>
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Timestamp>2011-11-21T11:57:12.3539044-05:00</Timestamp>
     </ErrData>
     <ErrData>max of 20 ErrData elements</ErrData>
 </root>
```

Expected OP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--Log the error count and error message-->
<root>
</root>
```

Actual OP:**EDITED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!--Log the error count and error message-->
<root />
```

Code :

```
XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(path);
try
{                   
    docs.Descendants("ErrData").Remove();
}
```

CODE:

Below is the code i am using ,the concept is the error count and timestamp are logged into XML file.Once its reached the threshold value,email will be send by function and remove all the nodes from the xml. Then when the next error comes it will start entering in to the xml file as below,

```
XDocument doc = null;
XElement el;
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{

    doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"));
    el = new XElement("root");
    //el = new XElement("root");
    XComment comment = new XComment("Log the error count and error message");
    doc.Add(comment);
}
else
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(path);
}
XElement p1 = new XElement("ErrData");
XElement p1Count = new XElement("Count", eventCount);
XElement p1Windowsatrt = new XElement("Timestamp", windowStart);

p1.Add(p1Count );
p1.Add(p1Windowsatrt );

if (doc.Root != null)
{
    el = doc.Root;
    el.Add(p1);
}
else
{
    el = new XElement("root");
    el.Add(p1);
}


try
{
    doc.Add(el);//Line throwing the exeception

}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
finally
{
    doc.Save(path);
}
```

Comment: are you sure the opening tag is missing and it's not just abbreviated as <root />?

Comment: Its my mistake,its the abbrevated root tag. But the problem is while using the same file next time to write the errors ,its throwing "This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.". I started with this error but overlooked the closing an d abbreavated tag.

Comment: Can you post the code that is trying to insert new `ErrData` elements (where you are getting the exception)?

Comment: As in - if you use the result .xml (below Actual OP) with the abbreviated tag with this code (`docs.Descendants("ErrData").Remove();`) you get that exception? Or is something else causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `docs.Root.Nodes().Remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

`<root />` is valid XML for a tag with no content (self-closing tags).  If you absolutely need an opening and closing tag you need to put some content in the root node like a comment or text.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is in your very first sentence:  "I am trying to remove all the nodes/elements from the XML file."  Which one is it?  Do you want to remove all nodes, or all elements?

There are five types of nodes in XML:  elements, text, comments, processing instructions, and attributes.  If you use "node" and "element" interchangeably, as you are here, you're going to have no end of trouble working with XML.

What you got, `<root/>`, is the correct output for code that removes all descendant nodes:  it's a single element named `root` with no content.

What you expect,

```
<root>
</root>
```

is a single element named `root` that contains a child text node containing whitespace, probably a newline.  The code you wrote removes all descendant nodes, not just descendant *element* nodes, and so it removed this text node as well.

Comment: I will spend more time in learning LINQ concepts in depth.Thank you.

Comment: These are XML concepts, not LINQ concepts.  You'd run into the same problems if you were using `XmlDocument` methods to do this.